# Updating User Access Denied Using REST API

Tags: php, rest, sugarcrm, suitecrm

REST calls are working properly on every module but when trying to update user data for the currently logged in user, I get an access denied error.

The Internet is full of examples for updating general records, but updating the user data seems like a special case.

Obviously, when accessing the CRM itself (web interface), the user can change his personal details, so it doesn't seem like a role/rights issue. Has anyone managed it with the REST API in updating user data such as name, last name, email, etc.?

*Note: It works when the REST user is admin, of course, but I'd like to avoid this alternative.*

Comment: where you are getting the error?? from DB?

Comment: @AnoopLL As the result of the REST call

Comment: non-admin user doesn't have access to user module which is causing this issue. so you have to go for alternative. I think for this sort of API call, use some Admin user login and then call set_entry.